# safe regex to find emails from html

Tags: python, regex

```
url ="https://www.siliconvalleypediatricdentistry.com/"
res=requests.get(url)
html=res.text
#re.findall(r'([\w0-9._-]+@[\w0-9._-]+\.[\w0-9_-]+)',html)
#re.findall(r"(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)",html)
```

I found plenty of questions regarding this but most of them are extracting "wrong" emails

I am getting this as output

```
['8b4e078a51d04e0e9efdf470027f0ec1@sentry.wixpress.com',
 'core-js-bundle@3.2.1',
 'whatwg-fetch@3.0.0',
 'requirejs-bolt@2.3.6',
 'svpdinfo@gmail.com',
 'svpdinfo@gmail.com',
 'SVPDinfo@gmail.com']
```

some of them are just JS scripts, is there a safer regex to use or module that does this?

Comment: Email addresses are more complex than often thought. Imo the easiest way is to use a simpler regex like e.g. `\S+@\S+` and *actually send an email to that address*.

Comment: @Jan how can I check if email exists without sending email ?

Comment: You can't.  And even if you do send, many hosts won't respond with an error if the username doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That works for me:

```
re.findall(r'([\w-]+@[\w-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{1,5})',html)
```

Basically, we just force the end to be letters (e.g. `.com`), so the JS scripts don't match

Comment: `\w` already include `[0-9_]`, so your character class can be shortened to `[-.\w]`.

Answer (score 1):

Just can try this:

```py
r'^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,6})+$'
```

Or you can use your our own regex and just check if the email address are valid with:

```py
from validate_email import validate_email
is_valid = validate_email('svpdinfo@gmail.com')
```

Comment: nice module, does it actually send an email if not then how does it check

Comment: It checks if the SMTP Server exists and can check if it that server has that email address without sending an email. More info at: https://pypi.org/project/validate_email/